# PostgreSQL error 22P02 invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I keep getting the 22P02 error: `invalid input syntax for integer: "{1,2,3}"` (see comment in service call).

Here is my service call:

```
...
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("mediabase.create_media", connection))
{
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.Add("title", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.title;
    command.Parameters.Add("uniqueFilename", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.uniqueFilename;
    command.Parameters.Add("description", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.description;
    command.Parameters.Add("categoryIds", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.categoryIds; /* here the value is "1,2,3" */
    command.Parameters.Add("typeId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.typeId;
    command.Parameters.Add("ownerId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.ownerId;
    command.Parameters.Add("statusId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.statusId;
    command.Parameters.Add("gpsLocation", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.gpsLocation;
    command.Parameters.Add("locationNameId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.locationId;
    command.Parameters.Add("uploadUserId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.uploadUserId;
    command.Parameters.Add("uploadDate", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.uploadDate;
    command.Parameters.Add("uploadIp", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.uploadIp;
    command.Parameters.Add("metadataId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = metadataId;
    command.Parameters.Add("sysEnvironment", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.sysEnvironment;
    command.Parameters.Add("languageId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.languageId;
    command.Parameters.Add("publicationIds", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.publicationIds;
    command.Parameters.Add("limitations", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = media.limitations;

    mediaId = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
}

pgTransaction.Commit();
...
```

And the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mediabase.create_media(
    title character varying, 
    uniquefilename character varying, 
    description character varying, 
    categoryids character varying, 
    typeid integer, 
    ownerid integer, 
    statusid integer, 
    gpslocation character varying, 
    locationnameid integer, 
    uploaduserid integer, 
    uploaddate character varying, 
    uploadip character varying, 
    metadataid integer, 
    sysenvironment character varying, 
    languageid integer, 
    publicationids character varying, 
    limitations character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
    declare _mediaId integer;
    declare _point varchar;
    declare _gps_location geometry;
    declare _id text;

    begin

    IF (gpslocation <> '') THEN
      _point = 'POINT(' || gpslocation || ')';
      _gps_location = ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText(_point, 4326), 900913);
    ELSE
      _gps_location = NULL;
    END IF;

    insert into mediabase.media (
        title, 
        unique_filename, 
        description, 
        owner_id, 
        status_id, 
        gps_location, 
        type_id, 
        location_name_id, 
        upload_user_id, 
        upload_date, 
        upload_ip, 
        metadata_id, 
        system_environment,
        language_id,
        limitations)

    values (
        title, 
        uniqueFilename, 
        description, 
        ownerId, 
        statusId, 
        _gps_location, 
        typeId, 
        locationNameId, 
        uploadUserId, 
        uploadDate, 
        uploadIp, 
        metadataId, 
        sysEnvironment,
        languageid,
        limitations)

    returning id into _mediaId; 

    -- insert category ids
    FOR _id IN SELECT string_to_array (categoryids,',')
    LOOP 
        INSERT into mediabase.media_categories (media_id, category_id)
        values (_mediaId, (_id::int));
    END LOOP;

    -- insert publication ids
    FOR _id IN SELECT string_to_array (publicationids,',')
    LOOP 
        INSERT into mediabase.media_publications (media_id, publication_id)
        values (_mediaId, (_id::int));
    END LOOP;

    return _mediaId;

    end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

As you can see in the service method, the input of parameter `categoryids` is the string `"1,2,3"`, and the `NpgsqlDbType` is `Varchar`. And at the stored procedure the input type is `character varying`.

Here is the execution log:

```
2013-01-17 08:56:42 CET ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "{1,2,3}"
2013-01-17 08:56:42 CET CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT into mediabase.media_categories (media_id, category_id)
            values (_mediaId, (_id::integer))"
    PL/pgSQL function "create_media" line 54 at SQL statement
2013-01-17 08:56:42 CET STATEMENT:  select * from mediabase.create_media(('Penguins')::varchar,('079117ec-676f-4022-9950-69e55c2a2600_Penguins.jpg')::varchar,('Description...')::varchar,('1,2,3')::varchar,(1)::int4,(1)::int4,(1)::int4,('')::varchar,(1)::int4,(1)::int4,('17/01/2013 08:56:42')::varchar,('::1')::varchar,(399)::int4,('dev')::varchar,(1)::int4,('1,2')::varchar,('Limitations...')::varchar)
```

Why is this error poping up?

Comment: Why not defining `characterids` as `integer[]`?  Then you can simply omit all the casts and use `generate_subscripts()` for the insert instead of looping.  Anyway, `string_to_array('{1,2,3}', ',')` results in `{"{1",2,"3}"}`.

Comment: @dezso I am much more of a C# developer then a SQL shark. Can you add a sample code which shows the use of `generate-subscripts()`, and the correct split of the string. Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `media.categoryIds` as added as a parameter is a String `1,2,3`, not an array? `{1,2,3}` is the PostgreSQL representation of the array `[1,2,3]` so maybe you're passing an array and nPgSQL is converting it for you? Otherwise, where are the brackets coming from?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, `media.categoryIds` is defenetly a string. I would actualy like to do that with an array, but had problems coverting. Lets say I'm sending an array of integers as @dezso sugested: 1) In the service method, which `NpgsqlDbType` should it be sent with? 2) What is the syntax for recieving it on the stored procedure side? Doing it like that will probably solv the problem.

Comment: Can you please enable `log_statement = all` in your session, or globally in `postgresql.conf`, then re-test and edit your question to show the exact text of the SQL statement executed by nPgSQL and the exact text of the error message, both taken from the PostgreSQL log files?

Comment: @CraigRinger The log statement is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem using @dezso and @CraigRinger tips. I'm now using an array of integers instead of comma seperated string. Here are the changes:

On the service call:

```
...
/* media.categoryIds is of type int[] now */
command.Parameters.Add("categoryIds", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = media.categoryIds;
...
```

On the stored procedure:

```
...
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mediabase.create_media(
    title character varying, 
    uniquefilename character varying, 
    description character varying, 
    categoryids integer[], -- changed type
    typeid integer, 
    ownerid integer, 
    statusid integer, 
    gpslocation character varying, 
    locationnameid integer, 
    uploaduserid integer, 
    uploaddate character varying, 
    uploadip character varying, 
    metadataid integer, 
    sysenvironment character varying, 
    languageid integer, 
    publicationids integer[], -- changed type
    limitations character varying)
...
...
    declare i integer;
...
...
    -- insert category ids
    FOR i IN SELECT generate_subscripts( categoryids, 1 )
    LOOP 
        INSERT into mediabase.media_categories (media_id, category_id)
        values (_mediaId, categoryids[i]);
    END LOOP;

    -- insert publication ids
    FOR i IN SELECT generate_subscripts( publicationids, 1 )
    LOOP 
        INSERT into mediabase.media_publications (media_id, publication_id)
        values (_mediaId, publicationids[i]);
    END LOOP;
...
```

Thanks again for the help on this.